# Is there a way to find command in PATH using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use gauge framework for testing, which has *gauge* command in my terminal. I would like to know how I can get path to this command within Python (just like *which* command in GNU/Linux).

I understand that it is somehow related to `os.environ['PATH']`, but, unfortunately, I can only find *PATH* variables in it, but not path to *gauge*.

So, what I would like to see is something like that:

```
# Windows example.
>>> function('gauge')
/c/Program Files/Gauge
```